# Grails - Spring Security Plugin - User has 'ROLE_NO_ROLES' after adding 'ROLE_ADMIN'

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, roles

I am developing a web app using Grails, and I am trying to use the [Admin Interface Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/admin-interface). For testing purposes, I created an admin user from BootStrap.groovy using the following lines of code:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def adminUser = User.findByUsername("episo_admin_root")
        if(!adminUser){
            print "Creating admin user... "
            adminUser = new User(username: username, emailAddress: emailAddress, password: password, birthDate: new Date(1, 1, 1),
                    sex: Sex.AGENDER, enabled: true, accountConfirmed: true, accountCreationDate: new Date())
            adminUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
            def auth = adminUser.addAuthority(Roles.ROLE_ADMIN)
            auth.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        }
}
```

I also added the following statement to check whether or not the user was getting the role:

`if(adminUser.authorities.any { it.authority == Roles.ROLE_ADMIN }) println "Admin role added."`

This check passes, and "Admin role added." is printed to the console.
Here is my configuration for Spring Security:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
                '/':                      ['permitAll'],
                '/home':                  ['permitAll'],
                '/home.gsp':              ['permitAll'],
                '/assets/**':             ['permitAll'],
                ...
                ...
                '/**/js/**':              ['permitAll'],
                '/**/css/**':             ['permitAll'],
                '/**/images/**':          ['permitAll'],
                '/**/favicon.ico':        ['permitAll'],
                '/admin/**':              ['ROLE_ADMIN']
        ]
```

And here is my configuration for the Admin Interface Plugin:

```
grails.plugin.admin.accessRoot = "/admin"
grails.plugin.admin.domains."Users" = [ "mypackage.User" ]
grails.plugin.admin.domains."My Groups" = [ "mypackage.Group" ]
grails.plugin.admin.domains."Security Groups" = [ 'mypackage.Authority', 'mypackage.UserAuthority' ]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugin.admin.security.role = "ROLE_ADMIN"
```

However, when I login as the new admin user and navigate to "/admin", I get the Apache Tomcat "HTTP Status 403 - Access is Denied" page, and the following debug info is logged to the console:

```
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin; Attributes: [ROLE_ADMIN]
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@5ff53bc5: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@d7469d37: Username: [PROTECTED]; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: [PROTECTED]; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_NO_ROLES
```

If you scroll sideways on that debug info, you will see that Spring Security sees "Granted Authorities" to be `ROLE_NO_ROLES`.

Am I doing something wrong when adding the role to the user? Why won't Spring Security see that I have granted this user `ROLE_ADMIN`?

I've spent hours trying to debug this and I can't understand what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; I removed the following line from the config file which fixed my problem:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRoleGroups = true
```